# Can't change Android versionName and versionCode

Tags: java, android, version

i just tried to change the version name of my android app from 1.0 to 1.0.1 and the code from 1 to 2 but every time i export the project in eclipse it changes back automatically. Someone there who can help me?

here is my androidmanifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.pedda.soundbox"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="de.pedda.soundbox.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Does `android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.1"` work ?

Comment: Have you saved your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: I just solved the mistake: Yesterday I simply took the AndroidManifest.xml in the bin folder instead of the main folder. thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project with a finder or a console, and remove manually `bin/AndroidManifest.xml`.

Then clean and build your project. Check with an other editor the bin/AndroidManifest.xml file. It should have the new version.